# "No module named ipython" error despite already installed

Tags: python, ipython

I am trying to launch ipython using the command: `python -m ipython`

When launched I get the following error : `C:\Program Files\Python36\python.exe: No module named ipython`

This is strange because when I run `python -m pip show ipython`, I get the following message :

```
Name: ipython
Version: 6.2.1
Summary: IPython: Productive Interactive Computing
Home-page: https://ipython.org
Author: The IPython Development Team
Author-email: ipython-dev@python.org
License: BSD
Location: c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages
Requires: simplegeneric, setuptools, decorator, pickleshare, traitlets,         
pygments, colorama, prompt-toolkit, jedi
```

I already ensured that all dependencies were correctly installed.
Could you please help me ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is actually spelled `IPython` (upper case I and P to start).

```
python -m IPython
```

will do.

Edit: confusion can arise because the pypi service allows the package name and module name to differ.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem by using below command:

```
pip install IPython==5.0 --user
```

`IPython` version needs to pair with python version, and I have a `python2.7`